# How to get random sequence form AES python

Tags: python, random, aes

I'm need to get random sequence form AES(random gamma) without encryption just sequence of random bits. I have IV and other parameters. That's real? I can't find this mode in the standard. Please help me how it do using PyCrypto.

Comment: If you want random bytes, just use [`Crypto.Random.random`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Random.random-module.html). What do you need AES for? It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve by that.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm want to get the same sequence on both sides with same parameters without any congruential generator or LFSR

Comment: So you want a seeded (deterministic) pseudo-random number generator. You really should use hashing instead of AES for that. Although, pycrypto has an implementation for an AES-based seeded PRNG: [`Crypto.Random.Fortuna.FortunaGenerator.AESGenerator`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Random.Fortuna.FortunaGenerator.AESGenerator-class.html)

Comment: @ArtjomB. ok, this generation have almost max entropy? I'm looking for something like white noise.